# How to connect to MongoDB Atlas using mongoose and an x509 cert?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, x509, mongodb-atlas

The driver connection details from mongoDB give a connection string like this.

> mongodb+srv://cluster-name.xxxxxxx.mongodb.net/?authSource=%24external&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&retryWrites=true&w=majority

The mongoose documentation says to use code like this.

```js
// Do this:
const username = 'myusername';
await mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${encodeURIComponent(username)}@127.0.0.1:27017/test`, {
  ssl: true,
  sslValidate: true,
  sslCA: `${__dirname}/rootCA.pem`,
  authMechanism: 'MONGODB-X509'
});
```

I have confirmed that my IP is whitelisted, yet I am unable to connect. Can someone point me to a working example?